# como buscar fechas en java en un db con jdatachooser

Tags: java, sql, java-8

buenas quiero almacenar datos en una db pero me sale error

```
@Override
public List<Ausentismo> list05(Date fechai, Date fechaf, Date fechaMesA, Date fechaMesS) {


    List<Ausentismo> list05 = null;


    String sql = "SELECT AU.COD_MOTIVO, AU.CODIGO, AU.FECHA_SALIDA, AU.FECHA_RETORNO, AU.DIAS_CIA \n"
            + "FROM RH_AUSENTISMO AU WHERE FECHA_SALIDA BETWEEN '01-07-2018' AND '31-08-2018' \n"
            + "AND FECHA_RETORNO BETWEEN "+fechai+" AND '30-09-2018' AND AU.COD_MOTIVO ='LS'";
    try {

        Connection cn = db.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement st = cn.prepareStatement(sql);
```

esa es la consulta

```
 private void btnGenerarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    Date fechaf = (Date) fechaFinal.getDate();
    Date fechai = (Date) fechaInicio.getDate();
    Date mesSig = (Date)  mesSiguiente.getDate();
    Date mesAnt = (Date)  mesAnterior.getDate();



    snl snl = new snl();
    snl.grabar_snl(fechai ,fechaf, mesSig,mesAnt,a, m);
```

esa es donde envió desde el jdchooser y el erroe q  sale es este.

> Error: ORA-03115: unsupported network datatype or representation

espero su ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema es que cuando concatenas la fecha `fechai` el query se corrempe.
Primero: porque no agregas las comillas simple y
Segundo: `fechai` concatenara con el format de fecha predeterminado.

Te pongo este ejemplo, para que veas el error:

```
Date fechai = new Date();

String sql= "SELECT * FROM RH_AUSENTISMO WHERE FECHA_RETORNO BETWEEN " + fechai + " AND '30-09-2030'";

System.out.println(sql);
```

Muy parecido a lo que tienes, pero mira como queda la salida:

`SELECT * FROM RH_AUSENTISMO WHERE FECHA_RETORNO BETWEEN Thu Dec 13 12:20:13 COT 2018 AND '30-09-2030'`

---

Lo que debes hacer es formatiar la salida de la fecha y agregar las comillas simples:

```
Date fechai = new Date();

SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
String dateString = format.format(fechai);

String sql = "SELECT * FROM RH_AUSENTISMO WHERE FECHA_RETORNO BETWEEN '" + dateString + "' AND '30-09-2030'";
```

Y la salida sera:

`SELECT * FROM RH_AUSENTISMO WHERE FECHA_RETORNO BETWEEN '13-12-2030' AND '30-09-2018'`

---

Algunas veces es mejor utilizar el [`TO_DATE`](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php) para no tener problemas entre ambientes ya sea tu maquina, el de pruebas, pre-produccion o produccion. Pero la mejor opcion es pasar las fechas con parametros.

Un ejemplo del `TO_DATE`:

```
SELECT * FROM RH_AUSENTISMO WHERE FECHA_RETORNO BETWEEN TO_DATE('13-12-2018','DD-MM-YYYY') AND TO_DATE('30-09-2030','DD-MM-YYYY')
```

Comment: consulta estoy usando jdatachooser osea la consulta seria asi  
@Override
    public List<Ausentismo> list05(JDateChooser fechai, Date fechaf, Date fechaMesA, Date fechaMesS) {

Comment: Pero si ya le pasas una fecha como parametro, para que quieres pasar todo el control.

Comment: Adicional en el metodo `btnGenerarActionPerformed` ya obtienes los valores, fijate como optienes la fecha.

Comment: gracias tu ayuda me ayudo a solucionar